# Serialize XML array, attribute to Object

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xml-serialization

How Can I define an object to deserialize the following XML:

```
<body>
<S1 A="1">
    <S2 B="1">
        <S3 C="1"/>
        <S3 C="1"/>
    </S2>
    <S2 B="2"/>
</S1>
<S1 A="2"/>
```

Comment: Define what? Could you be more specific?

Comment: there are ton of examples on how to deserialize xml into an object.  You've got to show some effort.

Comment: Can you give your example in well formed XML please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend to use [xsd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which can help in generating XML schema or common language runtime classes from XDR, XML, and XSD files, or from classes in a runtime assembly.

1. Open [VS Developer Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
2. Type `xsd.exe PathToXmlFile.xml /outputdir:OutputDir` and press `Enter` - this will generate `*.xsd` file
3. Type `xsd.exe PreviouslyCreatedXsdFile.xsd /classes /outputdir:OutputDir` and press `Enter` - this will generate `*.cs` file (class definition).

That's all!

Try!

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

Usings.....

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
```

Classes.....

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "S3")]
public class S3
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "C")]
    public string C { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "S2")]
public class S2
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "S3")]
    public List<S3> S3 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "B")]
    public string B { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "S1")]
public class S1
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "S2")]
    public List<S2> S2 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "A")]
    public string A { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "body")]
public class Body
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "S1")]
    public List<S1> S1 { get; set; }
}
```

Code.....

```
        string strXML = File.ReadAllText("xml.xml");
        byte[] bufXML = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXML);
        MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(bufXML);

        // Deserialize to object
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Body));
        try
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ms1))
            {
                Body deserializedXML = (Body)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            }// put a break point here and mouse-over deserializedXML….
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Your XML.....

```
<body>
<S1 A="1">
    <S2 B="1">
        <S3 C="1"/>
        <S3 C="1"/>
    </S2>
    <S2 B="2"/>
</S1>
<S1 A="2"/>
</body>
```

I added the end tag..... I am reading your XML in to a string from a file in the application build folder called xml.xml... you will need to get the XML string from somewhere else or create the xml.xml file and save your XML for the code above to work